# Would Like to Improve this Script

Tags: python

I was reviewing some scripts that I have saved and came across to this particular one; I feel like it can be improved without the need of using all the lower/upper case letters, any advice? I was thinking of using `str.lower`, but don't really see how to implement it

```
def all_but_not_numbs(s: str) -> int:
    """
    >>> all_but_not_numbs('asd123')
    3
    >>> all_but_not_numbs('E.666')
    2
    """

    num_letters = 0

    for char in s: 
        if char in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ.,':
            num_letters = num_letters + 1
    return num_letters
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `str.lower`, you could lowercase the character you are about to test so you don't need the uppercase letters. Characters that are `.` or `,` are not affected by `lower`. Also, use `sum` with a generator expression to make you code more compact and (IMHO) more readable.

```
>>> letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz,."
>>> s = 'E.666'
>>> sum(1 for c in s if c.lower() in letters)
2
```

Or you could use [`ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) defined in the `string` module:

```
>>> import string
>>> letters = string.ascii_letters + ",."
>>> sum(1 for c in s if c in letters)
2
```

In both cases, the `in` check will be linear (O(k) for k "good" letters), though. This should not be a problem for such a short list of letters, but to improve it further, you could turn `letters` into a `set` so that the `in` check will be O(1).

```
>>> letters = set(letters)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `regex` to find all letters and dots and take length:

```
import re

s = 'asd123'
print(len(re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\.]', s)))
# 3
```

Comment: That’s a really helpful module

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following method, basically, stripping the digits and using `len` to count number of remaing chars:

```
>>> s
'asd123'
>>> to_strip = '0123456789'
>>> len(s.strip(to_strip))
3
```

Or using `string.digits` from `string` module:

```
>>> s
'asd123'
>>> len(s.strip(string.digits))
3
```

EDIT: Following tobias_k comments, I suggest the following which is similar to Austing's answer but through different approach:

```
>>> s = 'abced@#$%123'
>>>
>>> import re
>>>
>>> to_strip
'0123456789'
>>> re.findall('[^{}]'.format(to_strip), s)
['a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'd', '@', '#', '$', '%']
>>> len(re.findall('[^{}]'.format(to_strip), s))
9
```

Which it says to look for all characters except(^) the ones mentioned after (^), which are the digits.

Comment: Does not work for other characters like $, %, -, *, (, etc., and if you extend the list of characters to remove, you are just inversing OP's problem (and making it worse, with a longer list of characters to write out). Also, `strip` will not remove characters in the middle of the string.

Comment: @tobias_k, answer updated, thank's for the head's up!

Answer (score 0):

Well I used `s.isalpha()`, `s.upper.isupper()`, and `ch in '.'`(didn't need `,`):

Now, my questions is about why Python says that my line  `if ch.isalpha():` is inconsistent?
error: `builtins.TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`

```
num = 0
for ch in s:
    if ch.isalpha():
        num = num + 1
    elif ch.upper.isupper():
        num = num + 1
    elif ch in '.':
        num = num + 1
return num
```